# Efficient If-Else Handling

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, embedded

I am working on a project where I collect data from a sensor and store the data in an array of size 3. Data storing is such that it always stores maximum value at index [2] and earlier maximum value pushed down to index [1] and one before that at index [0] and new data that comes in should be compared with the already present data and accordingly sorted in the array or be discarded.

This is how I am doing it

```
    if (New_value > three_values_list[2]) {
        three_values_list[0] = three_values_list[1];
        three_values_list[1] = three_values_list[2];
        three_values_list[2] = New_value;
    } else if (three_values_list[2] > New_value > three_values_list[1]) {
        three_values_list[0] = three_values_list[1];
        three_values_list[1] = New_value;
    } else if (three_values_list[1] > New_value > three_values_list[0]) {
        three_values_list[0] = New_value;
    }
```

I wish to do it more efficiently and not just comparing individually.

I had used ternary operator as well, but that seems too big and not quite readable, Is there any better way to do it?

---

Example input and output:

Input data comes serially, assume: `12 22 21 23 22 4 12`

Expected output: `23 22 21`

new value comes, `20`:
output should remain same: `23 22 21`

new value comes `28`:
output should be: `28 23 22`

new value comes `24`:
output should be: `28 24 23`

new value comes `28`:
output remains same: `28 24 23`

Comment: `a > b > c` does not mean what you think it means in C. I think you mean `a > b && b > c`.

Comment: When the new value is greater than the current maximum, the code discards the current minimum value and shuffles the the other two values down. So what does it mean for a value to be a minimum?

Comment: Why are new values equal to any of the stored values ignored? -- Would you mind to [edit] your question and provide several sets of input data and the expected output?

Comment: This is pretty much the way to do it. If you had more than only 3 slots, you could sensibly use loops. You can use loops anyway, if you want to, but it won't be shorter.

Comment: @thebusybee, I did not include equal to values because they will be eventually discarded and I don't need to change anything in the array as equal value is already present.

Comment: @thebusybee, I have added sample input outputs please let me know if it helps

Comment: From the example sequences, I assume you want to store the greatest three  unique values?

Comment: @IanAbbott, that's it! yes, thank you for putting it more straightforwardly.

Comment: The additions helps a lot, as we see. ;-) Now, what is "_efficiently_" for you? Fast running code, little source code, easy to understand, ...? At some point some instance has to compare the new value to at least 1 of the stored values, individually.

Comment: @thebusybee, yeah, all three points you mentioned for efficiency are my intentions. But, yes every value has to be compared individually, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Unfortunately such requirements drag in different directions. Fast running code is commonly not easy to understand and potentially bloated, and little source code (for example involving some sorting in one line) runs slower. So you need to decide which path you follow and where you break even. If you have hard limits, execute appropriate tests, else prefer simple code over fast running. You have now a lot of different answers to select from. (Hint: mark the best for you as "accepted".)

Comment: Rather than "greatest three unique values" I should have wrote "greatest three values not already encountered". I.e. the values are unique in the stored output list, but not necessarily unique in the input list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something as simple as keeping the three greatest values in a sorted order, it's fine to use 3 `if` statements.

But... your current code is both wrong and also too complex.

It's wrong because you test for intervals using code like `x < y < z`. While this is correct in math, it's wrong in C code. It does something rather different. The way to write it is `x < y && y < z`.

Your code is too complex because you do the interval testing. You don't need it. Just do:

```
if(New_value > three_values_list[2]){
  three_values_list[0] = three_values_list[1];
  three_values_list[1] = three_values_list[2];
  three_values_list[2] = New_value;
}else if(New_value > three_values_list[1]){
  three_values_list[0] = three_values_list[1];
  three_values_list[1] = New_value;
}else if(New_value > three_values_list[0]){
  three_values_list[0] = New_value;
}
```

Comment: This looks bit more efficient, thanks!

Comment: @Diracx Notice that this is fine as long as it's only 3 values. If requirements change and you need to keep e.g. 10 values then this isn't the way to do it...

Comment: Also it is unclear whether identical values should be stored or discarded.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not well defined:

- how is the array initialized? I would assume you store the first 3 readings in an ordered fashion. This part is unambiguous and can be programmed as an initial step.
- *new data that comes in should be compared with the already present data and accordingly sorted in the array or be discarded*  This part is unclear:

  - a new reading that is smaller than `three_values_list[0]` becomes the new minimum, but does the previous minimum get discarded or does it replace `three_values_list[1]`?
  - a new reading that is greater than `three_values_list[2]` becomes the new maximum, but does the previous maximum get discarded or does it replace `three_values_list[1]`?
  - does a new reading that is equal to `three_values_list[0]` or `three_values_list[2]` replace `three_values_list[1]` or get discarded?
  - does a new reading that is strictly between the minimum and maximum values get stored into `three_values_list[1]` or get discarded.

Once you specify these cases, the implementation becomes simple and straightforward.

Here is a simple one where any new value is stored in one of the 3 slots:

```
    if (initial_case) {
        three_values_list[0] = New_Value;
        three_values_list[1] = New_Value;
        three_values_list[2] = New_Value;
        initial_case = 0;
    else
    if (three_values_list[0] > New_value) {
        three_values_list[0] = New_value;
    } else
    if (three_values_list[2] < New_value) {
        three_values_list[2] = New_value;
    } else {
        three_values_list[1] = New_value;
    }
```

Here is an alternative where the previous minimum or maximum gets *sorted* into `three_values_list[1]`.

```
    if (initial_case) {
        three_values_list[0] = New_Value;
        three_values_list[1] = New_Value;
        three_values_list[2] = New_Value;
        initial_case = 0;
    } else
    if (three_values_list[0] > New_value) {
        three_values_list[1] = three_values_list[0];
        three_values_list[0] = New_value;
    } else
    if (three_values_list[2] < New_value) {
        three_values_list[1] = three_values_list[2];
        three_values_list[2] = New_value;
    } else {
        three_values_list[1] = New_value;
    }
```

Note however that it does not make much sense to choose either approach.  I would recommend you instead keep the minimum, maximum and average values (or the sum to avoid losing precision):

```
    int count = 0;
    double three_values_list[3];
    double New_value;
    ...
    if (count == 0) {
        three_values_list[0] = New_Value;
        three_values_list[1] = New_Value;
        three_values_list[2] = New_Value;
    } else
    if (three_values_list[0] > New_value) {
        three_values_list[0] = New_value;
    } else
    if (three_values_list[2] < New_value) {
        three_values_list[2] = New_value;
    }
    three_values_list[1] = (three_values_list[1] * count + New_value) / (count + 1);
    count++;
```

**EDIT:** Thank you for clarifying the question: you want to keep the 3 largest distinct values in `three_values_list[2]`, `three_values_list[1]` and `three_values_list[0]`.

Here is a simple solution, assuming the array is initialized with minimum values below the readings from the sensor:

```
    value = New_value;
    if (value >= three_values_list[2]) {
        if (value > three_values_list[2]) {
            three_values_list[0] = three_values_list[1];
            three_values_list[1] = three_values_list[2];
            three_values_list[2] = value;
        }
    } else
    if (value >= three_values_list[1]) {
        if (value > three_values_list[1]) {
            three_values_list[0] = three_values_list[1];
            three_values_list[1] = value;
        }
    } else
    if (value > three_values_list[0]) {
        three_values_list[2] = value;
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, my question was ambiguous,
 **1.** Three values that are stored are all maximum values when they arrived. But after they were stored, a new maximum came and pushed previous maximum down.
**2.** yes, the previous maximum becomes three_values_list[1], and new maximum is stored at index [2].
 **3.** It should be discarded, as same value is already present in the list, so list need not be changed.

  **4.** Yes values that strictly lies between three_values_list[2] and three_values_list[0] should replace three_values_list[1] 
IFF: previous three_values_list[1] < new_value

Comment: @chqelie, you have answered it nicely, but it is a bit diverging from my question, I wanted to store the greatest three values not already encountered(unique), and so at index [0] is not a minimum, but a maximum at some point after which 2 more maximum values came to be put at index [1] and [2]. Hope I am clear

Comment: @Diracx: I see you have clarified the question. I shall rephrase my answer later today.

Comment: I appreciate that you edited your answer. But I think 2 conditional checking is redundant only > is required. Thanks for your answer! as [@SupportUkraine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75399098/21072738) this asnwer

Comment: @Diracx: if you want the 3 largest values, 3 tests are indeed sufficient, but if you want to discard duplicate values, you need 2 extra tests to avoid storing identical values.

Answer (score 2):

For an array as small as 3 elements, your solution is fine as is. It realistically isn't going to get more efficient or more readable.

Well, besides your if statements. As written, they are seemingly redundant (you check if the value is less than the larger value, even though you've just checked against the larger value in the previous if) and wrong (in C, `x>y>z` actually compares the boolean value resulting from `(x>y)` to `z`). So you want something like `else if(New_value > three_values_list[1])` for each `else if` instead.

For a large array, you could consider using [`memmove`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) to shift the array down after a match, and a for loop to check all the elements in order from greatest to least to find the match. (edit: [Vlad from Moscow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75398849/20658329) is a good example of how to do something like this.) Since your array is implied to always be sorted, you could even use a binary search! But there is no need to do any of that in this case.

Comment: Wyatt, your answer is very apt, glad you replied. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll make changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are duplicated code in your code snippet.

Instead of using if statements I would write the following code

```
size_t i = 0;

while ( i < 3 && three_values_list[i] < New_value) i++;

if (i-- != 0)
{
    memmove( three_values_list, three_values_list + 1, i * sizeof( int ) );
    three_values_list[i] = New_value;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, the numbers stored in the list need to be unique, which could be accounted for by replacing `if (i-- != 0)` with `if (i-- != 0 && three_values_list[i] != New_value)`. Actually, I haven't checked whether that works properly yet! Also change `<` to `<=` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I tried this and as Ian said that is the only change requied.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in C :

```
void insert_value(int *three_values_list, int new_value) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (new_value > three_values_list[i]) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (i < 3) {
    int j;

    for (j = 2; j > i; j--) {
      three_values_list[j] = three_values_list[j - 1];
    }

    three_values_list[i] = new_value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not C code.

Comment: Updated with C solution as well

Comment: Kindly delete the JS part since that is off-topic here. The way SO works is that the tags to the question define the topic and scope on the question. You attract the right kind of audience by specifying the correct tag, so for C questions that is [tag:c] and for JS questions that is [tag:javascript]. Mixing unrelated programming language tags while asking a question or answering with another programming language than the question specified are both frowned upon.

Comment: You should remove the JS part, the question is specifically tagged as C

Answer (score 0):

You could only compare two values, so you need something like this:

```
}else if((three_values_list[2] > New_value) && (New_value > three_values_list[1])){
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Noted, I'll make this change.